# Google Analytics Tracker showing Tracking Not Installed

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, tracking

Using wordpress, I manually inserted the tracking code given to me by Google Analytics just before the  tag into my header.php file.  Google Analytics is still showing Tracking Not Installed.

here's the source code for my site:

view-source:http://funnykittenmemes.com/

Any ideas?

Comment: You mention "just before the tag" in your `header.php` file. Which tag, specifically?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the javascript is broken from cutting and pasting.

Easiest thing to do is use a plugin rather then edit theme files. Take a look at http://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=google+analytics for any number of plugins - simple to complex - that will work.

Most you simply enter your Google ID - and sometimes authenticate with your Google account - and the plugin takes it from there.

Comment: I copied the code several times to make sure it was the same code from Google Analytics.  I also used Wordpres's GA plugin to no avail. The plugin does not insert the GA code immediately before the "</head>" which is what GA instructs.  I've doubled checked the GA code and I can check again to see if it matches.

Comment: I used the Insert Header and Footer plugin and copied the GA code into the header but tracking still shows not installed.

Comment: Trackers still shows Not Installed but the Reporting is showing incoming Data so I'm going to assume the tracker code is working.